# Can't get rid of class from deleted module

Tags: magento2, module

I created a module, which I later deleted.
The homepage of my site loads, and my categories page loads, but my products pages don't load.

I get an error saying

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Company\Modulename\Model\Product\Attribute\FileUpload does not exist
```

That module doesn't exist. I've searched the entire project, and nothing that looks like that class exists.

I've delete var/viewpreprocessed, var/cache, var/page_cache, pub/static/frontend, pub/static/adminhtml, generated.

I've run setup/upgrade, setup:di:compile, setup:static-content:deploy -f, and c:c/c:f multiple times, and removed the record of the module from the db entirely, but it's changed nothing

Any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have kept the module before deleting it, you may check the folder Setup within the module root folder.

If the module installs anything in the database, it may have created attribute in the database (this is quite common) and these attributes would point onto Models that might have disappeared.

you would need to delete (manually is possible) these new attributes. Do keep a backup of the database before doing this of course

Comment: @Toan Tam a lot of those directories don't exist anymore, but even so, that didn't work.

Comment: That's probably it. It did add an EAV attribute. I'll look for it and delete it.

Comment: Herve, This helped me. Thanks! For those still investigating, if you query the `eav_attribute` table in your database you can sort or filter by `source_model` and see the offending class that is being called, but doesn't exist. You delete these attributes through the admin Stores > Attributes > Product page and that's it. You don't even have to re-compile.

Comment: thanks for this feedback @jon. You are right, using this table eav_attribute is the one to query. Your idea to handle the change from the backend is also useful for those who are not technical

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, I have this kind of issue. And I was able to fix it by running composer dump-autoload.

Can you try to run the following commands?

```
composer dump-autoload
rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ var/di/ generated/* var/generation/*
```

Comment: what does "composer dump-autoload" do  ?

Comment: It regenerates the list of classes that need to be included in the project.